# How can I use an initialize a static array with a known num of elements?

Tags: c++

I have an enum type with a last item 'num_of_types'. (that is, it will be 15, in example)
I'like to have a static array_of_types[num_of_types], to easily count the number of each type I create. 
My idea is to have: array_of_types[the_type]++;

But, I have no idea to declare and initialize this static array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
enum MyEnum
{
Type1=0,
Type2,
Type3,
NumTypes
};


// initialize the entire array with 0
unsigned countArray[NumTypes]={0};
```

After you declared that array you can use it as you mentioned:

```
countArray[type]++;
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
static TYPE staticArray[] = {
    VAL1,
    VAL2,
    ...
    VALN
};
```

or

```
static TYPE staticArray[MAX_ELEMS];
```

in case you do not want to initialize the elements when you allocate the array.

<del>What you cannot do *at the same time* is both specifying the number of elements and providing and initialization list.</del>

Comment: Why not?  I do it from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

You use it just like normal:

```
enum E
{
    A,
    N 
};

int main()
{
    int a[N];
    // Use 'a'...
}
```

In the above example, the variable `a` is defined as an array of integers, with the size `N`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
enum Types { TYP_1, TYP_2, /*...*/ num_of_types};
class A {
    /*...*/
   static int array_of_types[num_of_types];
};


int A::array_of_types[num_of_types];
```

This way you will create an array filled with default values for the array data type (which is zero for int).